# Redirect user to Angular route after success google auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I have a problem where I can't redirect user to angular route, like here's the example:

- I am on login page, click google login, redirected to google, successfully logged in, and after that i want to go in my app, like news feed.

What I did by far is with passport is within express app. Here are the routes and passport strategy for google.

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: ['profile', 'email']
}))

router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/'
}))
```

And this is the google strategy where I store user.

```
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: Config.google.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: Config.google.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: Config.google.CALLBACK_URL,
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        if (!req.user) {
            User.findOne({ 'google.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err) }

                if (user) {
                    if (!user.google.token) {
                        user.google.token = token
                        user.google.name = profile.displayName
                        user.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                        user.username = profile.displayName.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

                        user.save(function(err) {
                            if (err) { throw err }
                            return done(null, user)
                        })
                    }
                    return done(null, user)
                } else {
                    var newUser = new User()
                    newUser.google.id = profile.id
                    newUser.google.token = token
                    newUser.google.name = profile.displayName
                    newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                    newUser.username = profile.displayName.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) { throw err }
                        return done(null, newUser)
                    })
                }
            })
        } else {
            var user = req.user
            user.google.id = profile.id
            user.google.token = token
            user.google.name = profile.displayName
            user.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;
            user.username = profile.displayName.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err) { throw err }
                return done(null, user)
            })
        }
    })
}))
```

So how can I make this to redirect on angular route which is like localhost:4200/app/feed for example, which is the flow on normal email login.

Comment: You found a way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

can you configure it here and check

```
router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/'
}))
```

to

```
router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  successRedirect: '/app/feed',
  failureRedirect: '/'
}))
```

Comment: My backend is on localhost:3000, so that will return to localhost:3000/app/feed which isnt a route from angular, i am using angular for frontend, so that's the problem

Comment: can you try this and check what is the result, `successRedirect: ' http://localhost:3000/app/feed ',`

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. I dont want to redirect on backend, because I need to redirect them to my frontend app

Comment: I think, if you have proxy configured then the ports don't matter, you access all resources via 4200, passing configured routes to 3000. Therefore redirect suggested by @VivekKumar should work, IMHO.